# Flutter markdown editor with mention dropdown support on web

Tags: flutter, web, markdown, quill

I have actually spent a lot of time looking for a solution for this. Stackoverflow is my last resort. Before I dive in I would like to describe my requirements.

My requirements,

1. I need an editor like slack that automatically converts markdown to relevant TextStyle or html. For example if I type, ## Hello and press enter. it is styled as H2 styled text.
2. Moreover, I also need to show a dropdown whenever I press @ or # to select from a list of options.

In short, I need something like quip, slite or medium.

I was hoping that this will be easy in flutter, given half of these features are already there in Google's Gmail and other apps by google by havent yet found a single library that meets these requirements.

### What I have already tried?

1. **Quil**: I found out by flutter_quill but for that I have to stick to a toolbar on the top. And no mentions support.
2. **Zefyr and html_editor**: I have tried these, but they are very buggy and slow. Moreover, they have very limited documentations.
3. **Custom** [Flutter: Medium-like Text Editor](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/flutter-medium-like-text-editor-b41157f50f0e). This is the most promising solution but it is lacking one essential feature of text editor. The article proposes that I divide the entire input field into multiple text fields which I can control using state. But this has one big problem that is, what if I want to select the entire body of text. Any hacks on this will be well appreciated.

If you have any questions and if the question isn't clear enough, please free to comment down below.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet for HTML Editor which you have implemented

Comment: Hey, I have been testing it without source control so lost it. Anyways, I don't think it has dropdown support for mentions and tagging which is necessary prequisite for me. If you have any knoweldge about how I can achieve that with html_editor please let me know.